# I'm getting this error: The type or namespace 'Action' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm getting this error on public event Action `OnBeforeMove()` and I don't know why. What am I missing?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] float mouseSensitivity = 3f;
    [SerializeField] float movementSpeed = 10f;
    [SerializeField] float jumpSpeed = 5f;
    [SerializeField] float mass = 1f;
    [SerializeField] float acceleration = 20f;
    [SerializeField] Transform cameraTransform;

    public event Action OnBeforeMove;
    
    internal float movementSpeedMultiplier;

    CharacterController controller;
    Vector3 velocity;
    Vector2 look;

    PlayerInput playerInput;
    InputAction moveAction;
    InputAction lookAction;
    InputAction jumpAction;
    InputAction sprintAction;

    void Awake()
    {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        playerInput = GetComponent<PlayerInput>();
        moveAction = playerInput.actions["move"];
        lookAction = playerInput.actions["look"];
        jumpAction = playerInput.actions["jump"];
        sprintAction = playerInput.actions["sprint"];
    }

    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        UpdateGravity();
        UpdateMovement();
        UpdateLook();
    }

    void UpdateGravity()
    {
        var gravity = Physics.gravity * mass * Time.deltaTime;
        velocity.y = controller.isGrounded ? -1f : velocity.y + gravity.y;
    }

    Vector3 GetMovementInput()
    {
        var moveInput = moveAction.ReadValue<Vector2>();

        var input = new Vector3();
        input += transform.forward * moveInput.y;
        input += transform.right * moveInput.x;
        input = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(input, 1f);
        input *= movementSpeed * movementSpeedMultiplier;
        return input;
    }

    void UpdateMovement()
    {
        movementSpeedMultiplier = 1f;
        OnBeforeMove?.Invoke();

        var input = GetMovementInput();

        var factor = acceleration * Time.deltaTime;
        velocity.x = Mathf.Lerp(velocity.x, input.x, factor);
        velocity.z = Mathf.Lerp(velocity.z, input.z, factor);

        var jumpInput = jumpAction.ReadValue<float>();
        if (jumpInput > 0 && controller.isGrounded)
        {
            velocity.y += jumpSpeed;
        }

        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    void UpdateLook()
    {
        var lookInput = lookAction.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        look.x += lookInput.x * mouseSensitivity;
        look.y += lookInput.y * mouseSensitivity;

        look.y = Mathf.Clamp(look.y, -110f, 110f);

        cameraTransform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(-look.y, 0, 0);
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, look.x, 0);
    }
}
```

I was trying to create an event that basically gives a "warning" that it's about to do the movement calculation logic. I've imported the Input System so it should have worked, but I'm obviously doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Please add `using System;` at the top of your class.

See this reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=net-7.0

Answer (score 0):

`Action` is part of the `System` namespace; `System.Action OnBeforeMove`.

The error you get is where the compiler is when realising something is not right. Therefore you should examine that line and character.

What is `OnbeforeMove`, it is an `System.Action`.

Why does the compiler nag about it, there is no reference anywhere to `System`.

The compiler just doesn't know what to do but to inform you about what it doesn't know:

`The type or namespace 'Action'`... the compiler does not even know if Action is a type or namespace. And both is an assumption by the compiler.

`(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

That means exactly what is going on here. The assembly reference to System is missing. Most likely you did add the `System.Runtime.dll` as VS does this for you. But having either `System.` before `Action` or the use of the `using System` at the top of the file is needed.

If you get this error:

1. Did I make a typo!
2. Did I add a reference?
3. Is the assambly added at all.
4. **Check the corresponding error page at learn.microsoft.com.**

   (click the link of the error code in the error-list of VS)